# Inner Join Same Table With LEAD / LAG

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have data below

[image]

What I need is something like this

[image]

Is this possible to get data like this?

I do some research and getting insight using lead / lag function, but the result was not expected, heres what I tried

```
SELECT Id, Username, Distributor, 
    LEAD(Id) OVER (PARTITION BY Username ORDER BY Id) AS IdNew,
    LEAD(Distributor) OVER (PARTITION BY Username ORDER BY Id) AS IdNew 
FROM UserDist
```

[image]

--UPDATE--

as mention by @gotqn, yes i have already try added unique key for each data that have same Id

so for example i wanna get data from username joe with seq = 1

```
DROP Table IF EXISTS #Temp 
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
    Seq INT,
    Id INT,
    Username NVARCHAR(100),
    Distributor NVARCHAR(100)
)


INSERT INTO #Temp(Seq, Id, Username, Distributor)
select DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Username  ORDER BY IdDum) AS Seq,
Id, Username, Distributor
from UserDist

select * from #Temp A

Seq Id  Username    Distributor
1   1   Joe         RNN
1   1   Joe         CNN
1   1   Joe         SSN
2   2   Joe         DSS
2   2   Joe         DDK
3   4   Joe         GER
3   4   Joe         RIG
3   4   Joe         POL
3   4   Joe         MOD
1   3   Kelly       OPK
1   3   Kelly       DLC
2   5   Kelly       DERMA
2   5   Kelly       KOI
2   5   Kelly       DELL
```

Instead of like returning that i needed, it return redundant data

```
select * from #Temp A LEFT  JOIN #Temp B ON A.Username = B.Username AND A.Seq + 1 = B.Seq
WHERE A.Seq = 1 AND A.Username = 'Joe'


Seq Id  Username    Distributor Seq Id  Username    Distributor
1   1   Joe         RNN         2    4  Joe         DSS
1   1   Joe         RNN         2    5  Joe         DDK
1   2   Joe         CNN         2    4  Joe         DSS
1   2   Joe         CNN         2    5  Joe         DDK
1   3   Joe         SSN         2    4  Joe         DSS
1   3   Joe         SSN         2    5  Joe         DDK
```

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: why is the secondary ordering RNN>CNN>SSN for Joe ID 1? why can't it be CNN>SSN>RNN. Your new column of Seq doesn't help with this at all, I suspect you want a RANK not a DENSE_RANK, also you used a column called IDDum which isn't defined but is more likely the numbers you want to be using

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible because you are not able to order the data for each user in a unique way. You need to have additional column (for example row - id). It is not necessary to be part of the table definition, you can calculate it using `ROW_NUMBER` like this:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMER() OVER (PARTITION BY Username ORDER BY ... some unique criteria ...)
```

Then having the data ordered, you just need to join in to itself like:

```
SELECT *
FROM OrderedData DS1
LEFT JOIN OrderedData DS2
   ON DS1.[row_id] + 1 = DS2.[row_id]
```

The above will be the base query.

Comment: i already try this (updated in question) actually, but it return multiple set data with same value, what am i missing ?

Comment: @Heinrich your `Seq` column is not unique. As I said, it should be. For the sake of the test, you can change it to ` DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Username  ORDER BY (SELECT 1))`  and try.